# What's the difference between Firebase JavaScript SDK and react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am trying to use to use Firebase (Cloud Firestore) for a react-native app, to store my JSON objects.

I ve seen people using Firebase in their [apps](https://devdactic.com/react-native-firebase-todo/) (npm install firebase), and others using react-native-firebase.

Most blogs say that Firebase itself is meant for web, so their react-native support is none/less. While a few other [blogs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase) and firebase official [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html) say that Firebase supports react-native.

I am not sure which library to choose, for my react-native project, and what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [project description on GitHub](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase):

> React Native Firebase is a light-weight javascript layer connecting
>   you to the native Firebase SDKs for both iOS and Android which aimes
>   to mirror the offical Firebase Web SDK as closely as possible.
>
> Although the official Firebase JS SDK will work with React Native; it
>   is mainly built for the web and has a limited feature-set compared to
>   native.

So, you should choose it, for react native platform. This will allow you to use more features and also benefit from using native sdk's (speed, memory consumption, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It helped. Although, talking about "limited feature-set", my requirement includes a simple editing of an array in a JSON object, which Firebase JS SDK supports (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), but i couldn't find such method on react-native-firebase. I wonder if it is really mirroring !!!

Comment: @kernelman firebase actually doesn't work with arrays (at least not, as you would expect it to work), check docs

Comment: @kernelman The `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` operations are quite new additions to Cloud Firestore. There is an issue to track adding them to react-native-firebase: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1389. The [release notes](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/release-notes) show that `arrayContains` has been added to 5.0.0, with `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` support "coming" soon.

Answer (score 4):

Add up from Dima Rostopira's Answer.

You need to use JS SDK in react native when you use expo.
Because expo not let you add custom native modules.
Else go with react native SDK

Answer (score 4):

According to doc
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#usage-with-expo

if use expo, you **still** can use react-native-firebase instead of the https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk, but need plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: More detail to answer will help people in understanding the difference better.